# SAML option not available under API Connect Manager Portal section

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

The documentation for API Connect under section Publishing a product to Bluemix 
in step 6 mentions "In the User Registry and Invitation section, click the User Registry arrow and select SAML."

However, as shown in the attached figure there is no option for SAML. Using IBM ID as default does not show the API under Explore APIs at the URL.

[Picture](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/apis/catalog)

[Bluemix Login -> API Connect -> Explore API] even after the API is published.

[Developer Portal User Registry and Invitation Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXH52.png)

I can see the published API in the developer portal. Could you please let me know what could be the reason or what to check to get the API seen in the Bluemix Catalog.

Thanks

Srinivas

Answer (score 1):

The SAML option was changed to IBM ID.

When publishing an API, make sure you use a custom visibility instead of Public, then enter the Bluemix org name which should have the visibility.

Comment: Thank you Matt. It seems like I have done those steps as IBM ID comes as default. I sent you all the image snapshots. When you get a chance please take a look and let me know where I was doing wrong.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? If so, please mark the question as answered. Thank you!